# Css queries to replace something like the "vh" query

Tags: css, viewport

I've recently found myself messing with the "vh" css: it seems to work wonders but I am aware that it is not supported by most old browsers. I'm wondering if anyone could enlighten me to any alternatives to this: I am aware of the existence of the @media queries but I don't see how they could help me resolve my problem.

Basically, if I set the height of some of my elements to 90vh, they will respond nicely. However, with the height:90% they change depending on the other elements and not the viewport height. I'm wondering what people used to target certain viewports before vh was a thing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It was introduced because there is no easy alternative. 90% and 90vh are completely different. What old browsers are worried about?

Comment: Well: I saw that vh was enabled in chrome and firefox quite recently (2011-2012) and I figured there must have been a way to bypass this somehow. I guess I'm mostly worried about older versions of firefox and chrome, but it was mostly out of curiosity.

Comment: 2011-2012 is not "quite recently", it's "ages ago". Chrome and Firefox auto-update. Your issue if you have one is with IE8.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround or polyfill for `vh`. Although you could look at https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly.

The only logical reason for avoiding using it is if you need to support IE8.